# Google Apps Script, create the dropdown list with multi columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working on Google Spreadsheet to create a file to management my online shop.
Here are the things I was created in Excel

[image: 1]

Can I do the same with Google Apps Script.
Thank for helping, sorry cause my English not very well!

Comment: You can do the same thing but it may not be as easy depending upon you knowledge of google apps script.  Multiple Dependent Dropdowns can get complex.  Here's an example I did a while back: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Comment: As an easy (and probably limited) workaround: you start by building a dropdown with dynamic element (from different sheet, but only working for 1 column), and next to dropdown, you put =vlookup to find other informations linked to your selection